# js range/selection object - how to select entire text in selected line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, contenteditable

I'm using contentEditable div and when cursor is at the end of the first line, then click button, I would like to select the entire line of first line. (if I have cursor at the end of the second line, then button click would select entire line of second line and so on)

How do I achieve this using selection/range object?

I made simple test app here: http://jsfiddle.net/ehSkr/15/

My problem with code below is that it works when only simple text exists in the document how ever when any node comes in play sucn as **this** then selection gets confused somehow and not selecting the entire line.

Note: I'm using IE11 (or 10, 9, 8), that's why selection.modify is commented out because IE does not support such method unlike Chrome.

**html**

```
<div contentEditable='true'>
<span><b>this</b> is a pen</span><br />
<span>second line</span><br />
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = [];
    range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    console.log(selection);
    console.log(range);

    var startNode = selection.anchorNode;
    var endNode = selection.focusNode;
    console.log(startNode);
    console.log(endNode);
    range.setStart(startNode, 0);
    range.setEnd(endNode, range.endOffset);
    selection.addRange(range);
    //selection.modify("extend", "forward", "word");
```